# Finding the ration between 3 numbers if we know the sum (and we also know that the 1st > 2nd and 2nd > 3rd)?

Tags: calculus, ratio

I have this tale of poker hand rankings, the author has given only the top 20% of the ranked cards and he has stated that the 1st value (GPP) is more important than the 2nd (V) and the 2nd is more important than the 3rd (NP). So how do you get to the OVERALL numbers?
The values are normalized from 0-10 (or 1-10 or something like that i am not sure about that)

[image]

EDIT: what i have tried till now:
I tried playing with the ratio of the 3 values, and than normalizing them using  y = 1 + (x-A)*(10-1)/(B-A).. where A is the starting point (min value) and B is the end point (max value). I tried allot to fine tune them but i couldn't achieve the same results in OVERALL no matter what i tried and i tried 3:2:1 i tried 5:3:1.5, 9:7:7... and as much as i could think off.. but always one or more were out of sync of the others.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: Of course, i tried playing with the ratio of the 3 values, and than normalizing them using  y = 1 + (x-A)*(10-1)/(B-A).. where A is the starting point in (min) and B is the maximum value. I tried allot to fine tune them but i coudn't achieve it i tried 3:2:1 i tried 5:3:1.5 and as much as i could think off.. but always one or more were out of sync of the other values